Gradient of $\frac{x}{1-||x|| }$
If $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-||x||}$, then what is the $\nabla f(x)$?
I tried to do a simple quotient rule, which isn’t recommended for linear algebra, and I got $\frac{(1-||x||)\nabla x - x\nabla(1-||x||) }{(1-||x|)^2}$. I have already figured out that $\nabla ||x||= \frac{x}{||x||}$. This is where the problem comes in.. The second term in the numerator ideally becomes $\frac{x^ 2}{||x||}$. Now, this $x^ 2$  should ideally be $x^ Tx$ or $xx^ T$.
I tried to write $f(x) = x^ T\times\frac{1}{1-||x||}$ or $f(x) = \left(\frac{1}{1-||x||}\right)^ Tx$, but none of this helped.
How can I get the correct order of the vectors and their transpose into the gradient?

Here the gradient will be a matrix. You try to differentiate the vector with respect to vector

Yes, it will be a matrix, and the second term should be $xx^ T$.  But without relying on intuition that it should be a matrix, how can I mathematically show the second term would be $xx^ T$? how do I bring the transpose in?

https://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/edoc/imm3274.pdf is a book including derivatives of matrix and vectors, it should help. Then by using chain rule, you can get the result

I find it easier to differentiate with scalars instead of vectors. Differentiate $x_i/(1-|x|)$ with respect to $x_j$ i.e. take $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$.

From the book I suggest in the comment, page 14, $\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}}(1-\|\mathbf{x}\|)=-\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}$.
Hence,$$\begin{align*}
\nabla f&=\frac{I(1-\|\mathbf{x}\|)-\mathbf{x}^T(-\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|})}{(1-\|\mathbf{x}\|)^2}
\end{align*}$$
Then, furthure simplication can be preformed.

As @NNN suggested, it's easier to work with scalars:
$$\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\dfrac{x_i}{1-|\boldsymbol x|}&=\dfrac{\delta_{ij}}{1-|\boldsymbol x|}+x_i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\dfrac{1}{1-|\boldsymbol x|}\\
&=\dfrac{\delta_{ij}}{1-|\boldsymbol x|}-x_i\dfrac{1}{(1-|\boldsymbol x|)^2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(1-|\boldsymbol x|)\\
&=\dfrac{\delta_{ij}}{1-|\boldsymbol x|}+\dfrac{x_i}{(1-|\boldsymbol x|)^2}\dfrac{x_j}{|\boldsymbol x|}
\end{aligned}$$
If we run through all the indexes we finally obtain
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol x}\dfrac{\boldsymbol x}{1-|\boldsymbol x|}=\dfrac{1\!\! 1}{1-|\boldsymbol x|}+\dfrac{\boldsymbol x\otimes \boldsymbol x}{|\boldsymbol x|(1-|\boldsymbol x|)^2}$$

$f$ is a vector-valued function. $\nabla f(x)$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. Using chain rule,
$$\nabla f(x) =  \frac{(1-\|x\|)I + \frac{xx^{\top}}{\|x\|}}{(1-\|x\|)^2}$$
